# Rolling Average SQL

Tags: sql, average

Hi I have a dataset where I have Year Month and output variables with the values as following:

```
Year    |      Month      |    Output
2015    |       1         |     12
2015    |       2         |     24
2015    |       3         |     2
2015    |       4         |     3
2015    |       5         |     7
2015    |       6         |     3
2015    |       7         |     7
2015    |       8         |     6
2015    |       9         |     7
2015    |      10         |     8
2015    |      11         |     3
2015    |      12         |     6
2016    |      1          |     3
2016    |      2          |     6
2016    |      3          |     8
2016    |      4          |     9
2016    |      5          |     4
```

......... and so on...

I want to add a new column in the dataset as Rolling_Average 
Rolling_Average = Sum of previous 12 month Output/ Output of this month

for example : 
Rolling_Average (for 2015-7) =  output (2015-01) + output (2015-02) +output (2015-03) + output (2015-04) +output (2015-05) + output (2015-06) / output (2015-07)

I tried couple of queries online to get the output but it didn't work for me. Can someone please help me

Output Required is as follows:

```
Year    |      Month      |    Output  |  Rolling Average
2015    |       1         |     12     |    12
2015    |       2         |     24     |    0.5 
2015    |       3         |     2      |    18
2015    |       4         |     3      |    38/3
2015    |       5         |     7      |    45/7
2015    |       6         |     3      |    48/3
2015    |       7         |     7      |    55/7
2015    |       8         |     6      |    61/6
2015    |       9         |     7      |    68/7
2015    |      10         |     8      |    74/8
2015    |      11         |     3      |    77/3
2015    |      12         |     6      |    83/6
2016    |      1          |     3      |    86/3
2016    |      2          |     6      |    92/6
2016    |      3          |     8      |    100/8
2016    |      4          |     9      |    109/9
2016    |      5          |     4      |    113/4
```

The Query I tried is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    //CALCULATIONS
   Year,
   Month,
   Output,
   (sum(CAST(Output) AS DOUBLE)))
   over(order by  year,month   rows  between 12 preceding and 1 preceding )
   as Rolling_Average

   from my_table
   group by  Year,Month
   order by  Year,Month
```

It gives me error :
Syntax error: OVER keyword must follow a function call

Also I have tried other things

Can someone please help me in an easy way . I am using SQL Plx it is similar to SQL

Thank You!

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Thank you for the Swift Response . I am using Plx SQL

Comment: I have never heard of a database product named `PLx SQL` can you share a link  to the product's web site? The use of the window function looks correct to me (although `CAST(Output) AS DOUBLE)` should be `CAST(Output AS DOUBLE)`. Does it work without casting? `sum(Output)  over (order by  year,month   rows  between 12 preceding and 1 preceding )`

Comment: Isn't the "Rolling_Average" alias name maybe a bit misleading? With a name like that then one would expect rather a calculation like `AVG(Output) OVER (ORDER BY Year, Month ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Rolling_Average`

Answer (score 1):

You might have misplaced some parentheses

```
(sum( CAST(Output) AS DOUBLE ))) over (order by year, month rows between 12 preceding and 1 preceding ) as Rolling_Average
```

Versus:

```
SUM( CAST(Output AS DOUBLE) ) OVER (order by year, month rows between 12 preceding and 1 preceding) as Rolling_Average
```

You can also ROUND that result.

And those records already seem to be unique by Year and Month.
So there's not really a need to group on those.

```sql
SELECT 
 t.Year, t.Month, t.Output,
 ROUND(SUM(CAST(t.Output AS INT)) OVER (ORDER BY t.Year, t.Month ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)*1.0 / CAST(t.Output AS INT), 1)  as Rolling_Average
FROM my_table t
ORDER BY t.Year, t.Month;
```

And if the window functions aren't supported, then this will work:

```
SELECT 
 t1.Year, t1.Month, t1.Output,
 ROUND(SUM(CAST(t2.Output AS INT))*1.0 / CAST(t1.Output AS INT), 1) as Rolling_Average
FROM my_table t1
LEFT JOIN my_table t2 ON ((t2.Year = t1.Year AND t2.Month < t1.Month) OR 
                          (t2.Year = t1.Year - 1 AND t2.Month >= t1.Month))
GROUP BY t1.Year, t1.Month, t1.Output
ORDER BY t1.Year, t1.Month;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3cf4f2c2bbd5d627fed8296cdae84b24)*

Comment: I am using (CAST(t1.output) AS DOUBLE)) as output but it is giving me the error. CAST is required to be used as in here my database reads all the values as String initially so I use CAST to convert them into the required datatype

Comment: @Nik Ah, so it's not a number type. I see now. But anyway, that syntax should be `CAST(t1.output AS DOUBLE)`. I'm still unsure about what type of database you use though.  I don't know any "SQL Plx".  For example, if it were for MS SQL Server then I would suggest to use TRY_CAST to avoid errors with strings that don't contain number data.

Comment: @Nik Updated, now it should work with Output as a string type like VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

Try this(if you use sql-server)

```
Select * 
from tableName T
outer apply (
             select sum(output) Rolling_Average 
             from tableName T_in on T_in.year = T.year and T_in.Month <= T.Month 
            )x
```